# How to configure disk io scheduler on COS with GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-os

I'm using container optimized os (COS) on google cloud kubernetes engine (GKE `1.24.2-gke.1900`).

The default io scheduler seems to be

```
~ $ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
```

I want to configure the default io scheduler to `none` as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/optimizing-pd-performance#optimize_your_disks_for_iops_or_throughput_oriented_workloads).

Meanwhile, GKE will automatically mount disks and device id may change.

Finally, cos version

```
NAME="Container-Optimized OS"
ID=cos
PRETTY_NAME="Container-Optimized OS from Google"
HOME_URL="https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/support-policy#contact_us"
KERNEL_COMMIT_ID=6150cfec353314bdc7a9d98a82963b469d9011ea
GOOGLE_CRASH_ID=Lakitu
GOOGLE_METRICS_PRODUCT_ID=26
VERSION=97
VERSION_ID=97
BUILD_ID=16919.103.10
```

Comment: Refer to this official document for [installation instructions for Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers) may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Your link refers to GPU installation. I don't think it will help here.

Comment: Please go through the [doc](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/109223) may help to resolve your issue.